# R - Background colour on ggplot split across a diagonal?

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-color

Using R, library(ggplot2)

I have a ggplot that is a perfect square.  From the top left corner, to the bottom right corner, I have a line.

So say xlim(0,100), ylim(0,100) with geom_abline(intercept=100, slope=-1).

How do I make everything above the line have say a blue background and below a red?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(x=c(0,100), ymin=0, y=c(100,0), ymax=100)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=y, ymax=ymax), fill="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=ymin, ymax=y), fill="red") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=100, slope=-1)) +
  #geom_line(aes(x,y), lwd=1) +  # If you just want a line with the same extent as the data
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

And analogously for more general curves:

```
x=seq(0,100,0.1)
dat = data.frame(x=x, ymin=0, y=2*x + 3*x^2 - 0.025*x^3)
dat$ymax=max(dat$y)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=y, ymax=ymax), fill="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=ymin, ymax=y), fill="red") +
  geom_line(aes(x,y), colour="yellow", lwd=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Yer a wizard, @eipi10  Thanks for the help. Upvoted and accepted.